# Header shrink size based on scroll

Tags: javascript

With a fixed header, I'm attempting to change the height of a container based on scroll position (menu becomes smaller once certain distance is scrolled).

Here is the CSS:

```
section#homeBg{
    min-height:1000px;
    padding-top:200px;
}

nav{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#323D44;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And here is the JS which I would hope would have adjusted the size for me but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$("#body").scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 100 )
        $("nav").css("height", "100px");
    else
        $("nav").css("height", "45px");
});
```

Can anybody spot my mistake? Also I would like the solution to be smooth in it's transition in height but I don't think this solution will offer that...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQRm4/)

Answer (score 0):

see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tQRm4/3/)**

```
$(function(){
    // your code
});
```

and

```
$(document).scroll( function() {

});
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong now... do you have any advice on making the transition smoothed?

Comment: transition smoothed? for what?

Comment: So that the changing from 100px to 45px is a smooth transition as opposed to a quick snap.

Answer (score 0):

`#body` doesnt exists in your fiddle, try with :

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value < 100 )
        $("nav").css("height", "100px");
    else
        $("nav").css("height", "45px");
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/tQRm4/2/).